# What's the right way to do these symbols in HTML?

Tags: html

See those symbols over the red marks? I'm trying to do them in HTML, and came across this page. [Click Here](http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/character-entities.html) There are three way to do them I can see (Entity Name, Decimal Number, Hex Number). Which one should I use so it'll appear without problems across all browsers.

[image: Symbols]

Comment: Any of those options will work fine.

Comment: They are all the same.

Comment: I prefer the named one for readability. There is no real difference though. Pick one and it will work.

Comment: I'd use actual characters myself. It's the most readable approach (and saves a few bytes).

Comment: @Quentin - With any reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For † `&#8224;` insert this in your html code.

For †† `&#8224;&#8224;` insert this.

For ‡ `&#8225;` insert this

For more of these kindly go [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

These codes will work on all browsers.